# Android LinearLayout background truns black

Tags: android, layout

Hi i used linearlayout and its property android:background to make border color of it grey.
When i switch to android 4.1., from 6.0  layout background turns black (whole background not just 3dip like set).

```
border.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke
       android:width="3dip"
       android:color="#d3d3d3" />
</shape>
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: set the background color directly, not only stroke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the background color for your shape.
On newer Android versions this is transparent, but on older ones it is black.
Just add a transparent solid to your XML to fix this.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
  <stroke
       android:width="3dip"
       android:color="#d3d3d3" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add property `**<solid android:color="YOUR COLOR" />**`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke
       android:width="3dip"
       android:color="#d3d3d3" />


    <solid android:color="#F9671E" />  // for background color.You can change

</shape>
```